# Script to take the backup

Tags: mysql, linux, backup, redmine

im using redmine 2.2.0 and I need a script to take the mysql and attatcment backup.Currently I'm using a script as given below.But I think it is giving a wrong output as the backup contains only 4 k.b can anyone please help....

```
DATE=`date +"%Y%m%d"`
BACKUP_DIR=/data/backup/backup
DB_USER="root"
DB_PASS="password"
REDMINE_HOME=/data/redmine/apps/redmine/htdocs/files
DB_CHARSET=utf8
export smtp=smtprelay.intra.host.com:25

# delete old backups
#find $BACKUP_DIR -maxdepth 1 -type d -mtime +62 -exec rm -rf {} \;

# create backup dir
mkdir -p $BACKUP_DIR/$DATE

# backup db
/data/redmine/mysql/bin/mysqldump -u $DB_USER -p${DB_PASS} --single-transaction --default-character-set=${DB_CHARSET} bitnami_redmine  > $BACKUP_DIR/${DATE}/redmine_dbdump.sql |mailx -r redmine@coriant.com -s "Redmine Dev db backup complete"  viju.p@xxx.com <<< "Redmine Dev db backup complete on ${DATE}"

# backup redmine
tar -pzcf $BACKUP_DIR/${DATE}/redmine_files.tar.gz -C $REDMINE_HOME . |mailx -r redmine@coriant.com -s "Redmine Dev File backup complete"  viju.p@xxx.com <<< "Redmine Dev File backup complete on ${DATE}"
```

Comment: what is the size of redmine_dbdump.sql ? Is db dump happens properlly? or you face problem only in tar redmine_files.tar.gz

Comment: Naggappan RM : db dump siz around 600 mb and db dump happens properly.But dont know where the problem happens